# Firebase Function throws an error: returned undefined, expected Promise or value. How do I resolve this

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my .ts file, I am using the then method and using the catch block to handle errors in the final return statement. This is a Firestore triggered background function and basically I am doing 3 things when a document is created 
1. Copy the data to another document in Firestore 
2. Send an FCM notification
3. Creating a JSON object called "notificationObject" and adding that to another document at Firestore

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

//When client followes a user, a firestore .onCreate() background function is triggered to
//1.add follower to the followee's followers sub collection
//2.an FCM notification to sent to the users
//3.A Notification doc is added to Notification Sub Collection
export const addTheNewFollower = functions.region('asia-east2').firestore.document
  ('Users/{followerUserId}/following/{followeeUserId}').onCreate((data, context) => {

  //get follower and followee Uids for identification
  const followeeUid = context.params.followeeUserId
  //for identification and notification payload data (Intent Extras for client)
  const followerUid = context.params.followerUserId

  //Get Follower user details that needs to be duplicated to the Followee's following Sub Coll
  //And also added to the notification Payload data
  admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(followerUid).get().then((doc:{ exists: any; data: () =>         
any }) => {

//Extracting this separately as this need not be copied to the Followers sub-collection
const followerImageUrl = doc.data().DOWNLOAD_URL

//This data will be copied to the followers sub collection
const followerData = {
  name:  doc.data().name,
  uid: followerUid,
  userName: doc.data().userName,
}


  //get the notification token of the followee to identify & send notification to his device
  admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(followeeUid).collection('notificationToken')
    .doc('theNotificationToken').get().then((notificationTokenDoc:{ exists: any; data: () => any })     
=> {

  const followeeNotificationToken = notificationTokenDoc.data().notificationToken

  //Create the Notification Payload content
  const notificationPayload = {
    notification: {
  title: 'You have a new follower!',
  body: `${followerData.userName}`,
  clickAction: ".People.PersonProfileActivity",
  image: `${followerImageUrl}`
    },
    data: {
  ACTIVITY_NAME: "PersonProfileActivity",
  //The below field name to be same as the one used in the client
  PERSON_UID_INTENT_EXTRA: followerUid,
  PERSON_NAME_INTENT_EXTRA: followerData.name,
  PERSON_USERNAME_INTENT_EXTRA: followerData.userName,
  //If the app is in the foreground then this channel will be used to trigger a notification and this     
//channel has to
  //be created at the client else, this will fail
  CHANNEL_ID: "Follow Update ID"
}
  }

  //random 11 digital Notification Doc Id
  const randomNotificationDocId = (Math.random() * 100000000000).toString()

  const notificationObject = {
message:`${followerData.userName} started following you`,
receivedTime: Date.now(),
//This is needed for client to access this doc and update the wasClicked field
notificationDocId: randomNotificationDocId,
senderName: followerData.name,
senderUid: followerData.uid,
//this will be false by default, will turn true at client when clicked
wasClicked: false,
//this type has to be same as in the client
notificationChannelId: "Follow Updates",
intentToActivity: "PersonProfileActivity",
intentExtrasUid: followerData.uid,
intentExtrasName: followerData.name,
intentExtrasUserName: followerData.userName,
  }

//Add the follower to the followee sub-collection

 admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(followeeUid).collection('followers').doc(followerUid)
.set(followerData)

//Add the notification doc to the user's notification sub collection
    admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(followeeUid).collection('Notifications')
.doc(randomNotificationDocId).set(notificationObject)

//Send the notification to the user
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(followeeNotificationToken,     
notificationPayload).then(function(response: any) {
  console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
  })
  .catch(function(error: any) {
  console.log("Error sending message:", error);

      })

    })

  })
})
```

The function complete as expected but I get the "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" at the Firebase console. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here

Comment: Your code is ignoring a lot of promises.  It's not sufficient to return just the last one - you have to handle all of them, then return a single promise that resolves when all of the async work is complete.

Comment: Hi Doug, I just watched your series on Javascript promises for Cloud Functions on YouTube and resolved this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I had a total of 5 methods in this file. I had to chain 2 of them using the 'then()' method and added the 3 methods in the bottom to an Array called promises and returned them as a promise using the Promise.all(promises) command.

Here is my final code

```
export const addTheNewFollower = functions.region('asia-east2').firestore.document
('Users/{followerUserId}/following/{followeeUserId}').onCreate((data, context) => {


//get follower and followee Uids for identification
const followeeUid = context.params.followeeUserId
//for identification and notification payload data (Intent Extras for client)
const followerUid = context.params.followerUserId

//Get Follower user details that needs to be duplicated to the Followee's following 
//Sub Coll
//And also added to the notification Payload data
return admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(followerUid).get().then((doc:{ 
exists: any; data: () => any }) => {

//Extracting this separately as this need not be copied to the Followers sub-    
//collection
const followerImageUrl = doc.data().DOWNLOAD_URL

//This data will be copied to the followers sub collection
const followerData = {
  name:  doc.data().name,
  uid: followerUid,
  userName: doc.data().userName,
}


//get the notification token of the followee to identify & send notification to his 
//device
return admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(followeeUid)
.collection('notificationToken')
.doc('theNotificationToken').get().then((notificationTokenDoc:{ exists: any; data: () 
=> any }) => {

  const followeeNotificationToken = notificationTokenDoc.data().notificationToken

//Create the Notification Payload content
const notificationPayload = {
notification: {
  title: 'You have a new follower!',
  body: `${followerData.userName}`,
  clickAction: ".People.PersonProfileActivity",
  image: `${followerImageUrl}`
},
data: {
  ACTIVITY_NAME: "PersonProfileActivity",
  //The below field name to be same as the one used in the client
  PERSON_UID_INTENT_EXTRA: followerUid,
  PERSON_NAME_INTENT_EXTRA: followerData.name,
  PERSON_USERNAME_INTENT_EXTRA: followerData.userName,
  //If the app is in the foreground then this channel will be used to trigger a 
notification and this channel has to
  //be created at the client else, this will fail
  CHANNEL_ID: "Follow Update ID"
}
}

//random 11 digital Notification Doc Id
const randomNotificationDocId = (Math.random() * 100000000000).toString()

const notificationObject = {
message:`${followerData.userName} started following you`,
receivedTime: Date.now(),
//This is needed for client to access this doc and update the wasClicked field
notificationDocId: randomNotificationDocId,
senderName: followerData.name,
senderUid: followerData.uid,
//this will be false by default, will turn true at client when clicked
wasClicked: false,
//this type has be same as in the client
notificationChannelId: "Follow Updates",
intentToActivity: "PersonProfileActivity",
intentExtrasUid: followerData.uid,
intentExtrasName: followerData.name,
intentExtrasUserName: followerData.userName,
}


const promises = []
  //Add the follower to the followee sub-collection
  const p = admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(followeeUid)
.collection('followers').doc(followerUid).set(followerData)
  promises.push(p)
  //Add the notification doc to the user's notification sub collection
  const p1 = admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(followeeUid)
.collection('Notifications').doc(randomNotificationDocId).set(notificationObject)
  promises.push(p1)
  //Send the notification to the user
  const p2 = admin.messaging().sendToDevice(followeeNotificationToken, 
notificationPayload)
  promises.push(p2)

  return Promise.all(promises)
})

})

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Return Promise.all([
    admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(followeeUid).collection('followers').doc(followerUid).set(followerData)
    admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(followeeUid).collection('Notifications').doc(randomNotificationDocId).set(notificationObject)
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(followeeNotificationToken, notificationPayload)
])
```

If you want to update more fields in Firestore or Realtime Database, put them in this `return Promise.all([ ... ])` statement.

Comment: @AnudeepAnanth can you try removing the `.then` and `.catch` ?

Comment: Thanks Dharmaraj, I implemented this for last 3 functions that I have but I still had the error because there are 2 other functions in file that were not being handled with a promise. So I chained all of them ( 5 in total ) and the error went away